# Errors in declaration when trying to parse a csv file

Tags: string, perl, parsing, csv, text-parsing

I'm trying to parse a CSV file that is formatted like this:

```
    dog cats,yellow blue tomorrow,12445
    birds,window bank door,-novalue-
    birds,window door,5553
    aspirin man,red,567
```

(there is no value where -novalue- is written)

---

```
use strict;
use warnings;


my $filename = 'in.txt';
my $filename2 = 'out.txt';

open(my $in, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)
or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

my $word = "";

while (my $row = <$in>) {
    chomp $row;

    my @fields = split(/,/,$row);

    #Save the first word of the second column
    ($word) = split(/\s/,$fields[1]);

    if ($word eq 'importartWord')
    {
        printf $out "$fields[0]".';'."$word".';'."$fields[2]";
    }   
    else #keep as it was
    {
        printf $out "$fields[0]".';'."$fields[1]".';'."$fields[2]";
    }
```

---

```
Use of uninitialized value $word in string ne at prueba7.pl line 22, <$in> line 10.
```

No matter where I define $word I cannot stop receiving that error and can't understand why. I think I have initialized $word correctly. I would really appreciate your help here.

Please if you are going to suggest using Text::CSV post a working code example since I haven't been able to apply it for the propose I have explained here. That's the reason I ended up writing the above code.

---

PD:
   Because I know you are going to ask for my previous code using Text::CSV, here it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ sep_char => ';', binary => 1 }) or 
                    die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV->error_diag ();


#directorio donde esta esc_prim2.csv
my $file = 'C:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\GIS\perl\esc_prim2.csv';
my $sal = 'C:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\GIS\perl\esc_prim3.csv';


open my $data, "<:encoding(utf8)", "$file" or die "$file: $!";
open my $out, ">:encoding(utf8)", "$sal" or die "$sal: $!";

$csv->eol ("\r\n");


#initializing variables
my $row = "";
my $word = "";
my $validar = 0;
my $line1 = "";
my @mwords = [""];#Just a try to initialize mwords... doesn't work, error keeps showing


#save the first line with field names on the other file
$line1 = <$data>;
$csv->parse($line1);
my @fields = $csv->fields();
$csv->print($out,[$fields[0], $fields[1], $fields[2]]);



while ($row = <$data>) {

    if ($csv->parse($row)) {
        @fields = $csv->fields();

        #save first word of the field's second element 
        @mwords = split (/\s/, $fields[1]);

        #keep the first one
        $word = $mwords[0];

        printf($mwords[0]);

        #if that word is not one of SAN, EL y LA... writes a line in the new file with the updated second field.
        $validar = ($word ne 'SAN') && ($word ne 'EL') && ($word ne 'LA');
        if ($validar)
        {
            $csv->print($out,[$fields[0], $word, $fields[2]]);
        }
        else { #Saves the line in the new file as it was in the old one.
            $csv->print($out,[$fields[0], $fields[1], $fields[2]]);
        }


    } else {#error procesing row
        warn "La row no se ha podido procesar\n";
    }
}

close $data or die "$file: $!";
close $out or die "$sal: $!";
```

Here the line where $validar is declared brings the same error of "uninitialized value" although I did it.

I also tried the *push @rows, $row;* approach but I don't really know how to handle the $rows[$i] since they are references to arrays (pointers) and I know they can't be operated as variables... Couldn't find a working example on how to use them.

Comment: What is line 22? What's on line 10 of the input?

Comment: NÂ° 107 9 de Julio;alberdi juan bautista 942;4724473\n
NÂ° 1078 John F. Kennedy;grandoli 4800;4729682\n
NÂ° 1080 Gabriela Mistral;san lorenzo 8154;4727581\n

Comment: Input is like that... 
And these are lines that cause trouble in the upper code 
($word) = split(/\s/,$fields[1]);
 
if (($word ne 'SAN')&&($word ne 'LA')&&($word ne 'EL'))

These line produce the error I posted

Comment: Please note that I wrote \n in the example of the input because I wasn't able to insert a line-break when editing the comment

Comment: John Kennedy seems to have no `$fields[1]`, hence the warnings (it's not an error).

Comment: I thought the way to refer to an element of an array was this:
my @array = [3, 2, 3, 4, 6];
my $3rd_element_of_array = $array[2];

Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Clarification: the file I'm using is really a semicolon-separed-value one but for simplicity sake I posted that was csv initially.
John Kennedy does have a $fields[1]!=0
Its value is "grandoli 4800"

Comment: @user2348235: You should use round brackets to initialise an array - `my @array = (3, 2, 3, 4, 6)`. Square brackets are used to initialise an array reference - `my $array_ref = [3, 2, 3, 4, 6]`.

Comment: Thanks Dave for the clarification ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the error. It's not a problem with the declaration of the variable, but with the data that you're putting into the variable.

> Use of uninitialized value

This means that you are trying to use a value that is undefined (not undeclared). That means you are using a variable that you haven't given a value.

You can get more details about the warning (and it's a warning, not an error) by adding `use diagnostics` to your code. You'll get something like this:

> (W uninitialized) An undefined value was used as if it were already
>       defined.  It was interpreted as a "" or a 0, but maybe it was a mistake.
>       To suppress this warning assign a defined value to your variables.
>
> To help you figure out what was undefined, perl will try to tell you
>       the name of the variable (if any) that was undefined.  In some cases
>       it cannot do this, so it also tells you what operation you used the
>       undefined value in.  Note, however, that perl optimizes your program
>       and the operation displayed in the warning may not necessarily appear
>       literally in your program.  For example, "that $foo" is usually
>       optimized into "that " . $foo, and the warning will refer to the
>       concatenation (.) operator, even though there is no . in
>       your program.

So, when you're populating `$word`, it's not getting a value. Presumably, that's because some lines in your input file have an empty record there.

I have no way of knowing whether or not that's a valid input for your program, so I can't really give any helpful suggestions on how to fix this.

Comment: Yes, that was the warning cause, an empty line in the input text file. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The error message you provided ends with: `line 22, <$in> line 10.` but your question doesn't show line 10 of the data (`$in`) requiring some speculation in this answer - but, I'd say that the second field, `$field[1]`, of line 10 of `in.txt` is empty.

Consequently, this line: `($word) = split(/\s/,$fields[1]);` is causing `$word` to be undefined.  As a result, some use of it latter - be it the `ne` operator (as displayed in the message) or anything else is going to generate an error.

As an aside - there's little point in interpolating a variable in a string on its own; instead of `"$fields[0]"`, say `$fields[0]` unless you're going to put something else in there, like `"$fields[0];"`. You may want to consider replacing

```
printf $out "$fields[0]".';'."$word".';'."$fields[2]";
```

with

```
printf $out $fields[0] . ';' . $word . ';' . $fields[2];
```

or

```
printf $out "$fields[0];$word;$fields[2]";
```

Of course, TMTOWTDI - so you may want to tell me to mind my own business instead. :-)

Comment: As you and Dave pointed out the warning was appearing due to an empty line on the input file... I know that you entered your answer first, but I think Dave one is going to be more enlightening for newbies entering this question so I'm going to select his answer as solution. I wish I could select both since both of you are right on point but I can't.

Comment: Your motivation is to help newbies and you've acknowledged my answering first - I'm happy with that.